# what's the difference between the ls and `ls` in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hello guys i like to know what's the difference in the bash i used `ls` without `` ` ` `` in bash so my program did not work and when i add `` ` ` `` it  works, what's the object of it

```
for i in `ls`
do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        echo $i
        let j=$j+1
    fi
    if [ -f $i ]
    then
        echo $i
        let k=$k+1
    fi
    if [ -x $i ]
    then
        echo $i
        let l=$l+1
    fi
done
echo "Il y a $j répertoires, $k fichiers et $l exécutables dans $rep"
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: If this other question doesn’t answer yours please [edit], make clear how it is different and mention me with @dessert in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

`ls` (or any command) returns the command results to a variable. Just the command by itself returns the results to stdout ("standard out" - output to the terminal).

Another syntax you'll see that means the exact same things is $(ls). That also returns the results to a variable.

So to expand your code to make it a bit more understandable:

```
DIRECTORIES=`ls`
for i in $DIRECTORIES
do
...
done
```

and just to demonstrate a bit more what's going on here:

```
echo $DIRECTORIES
```

will print the directory listing from ls to stdout (to the terminal)

Comment: To which variable are the command results returned in `for i in $(command)`? It’s rather that `$(command)` is replaced by `command`’s output.